# Get dropdown list with unique items in gsp, grails

Tags: grails, gsp

On my gsp-page I've dropdown list. The code below:

```
<g:select name="tablePlacesAvailable" from="${tableInfo}" 
          optionValue="${{it.placesInTableAmount}}" 
          optionKey="placesInTableAmount" value=""/>
```

It shows non-unique results. How to fix it?

Comment: Can you try doing 'tableInfo.unique()' in from attribute

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your code as per following .

```
 <g:select name="tablePlacesAvailable" from="${tableInfo.unique()}" optionValue="${{it.placesInTableAmount}}" optionKey="placesInTableAmount" value=""/>
```